# TestFairy NSLogs on iOS10 for Cordova

Tags: testfairy

I am new to test fairy and asked support but I did not hear from them so trying here.

The problem is that I cannot see the raw logs window within the session on the iOS app but I can see it when in android or when I run the app on the iPhone Simulator.

I followed the instructions to the letter to export the app as adhoc ecc...

Here is the api documentation.
https://docs.testfairy.com/FAQ.html

Oh I should also mention that I have a cordova / ionic app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jason, I work on the TestFairy team, and I'm sorry we didn't get back to your support ticket in time. Are you testing on a device running iOS 10? There is an existing issue with capturing logs in iOS 10. Please see https://docs.testfairy.com/iOS_SDK/Integrating_iOS_SDK.html for more information on how you can capture logs on iOS 10.

Comment: @VijaySharma thanks you did answer me today via email. Thanks will have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to TestFairy amazing support especially @VijaySharma here is the solution for those in need.

Find the .pch header file in Platforms > iOS > MyApp > MyApp-Prefix.pch

In the header add the following.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestFairy.h"
#define NSLog(s, ...) do { NSLog(s, ##__VA_ARGS__); TFLog(s, ##__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
#endif
```

Save the file and Rebuild the app.

Also if you want to show all the logs make sure you have this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

All set!